# Site Logo Propagation

Tags: 2010, site

I have created a site and replaced the site logo icon with one I created in the site settings. However, if I create additional pages in the site they display the top bar as expected but with the default logo. How can I change it for all the pages in a site?

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you 'replaced the site logo icon' as there are a few ways to do this

Comment: site actions > Site settings > look and feel > title description and icon

Comment: I should say that it appears on the default.aspx page(that has the typical navigation elements), but not on pages created later.

Comment: are these custom pages/page layouts?

Comment: Also, what kinds of pages are you creating?

Comment: Just using SP designer, adding a new web part page - uses generic logo. Using the TTW 'site actions>new page', I get the new logo I intended.

Comment: In SPD, the ones that 'work' are labeled 'wiki pages'. Odd. Adding a new ASPX page from SPD works as well. Likewise, those are labeled as 'wiki pages'.

Comment: Gah. This is a known issue - http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/sharepoint-site-logo-url-limitations-site-pages-vs-web-part-pages/